# Facing issue in react-native-smartconfig for ios

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native

i am using react-native-smartconfig, it is working fine with android and ios below 16 version but it's not working with ios version 16, please help me to resolve this issue, thanks in advance. my react-native version is : "0.59.10".

Comment: Check [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-smartconfig?activeTab=versions). This package is updated 6 year ago. So better if you will find alternative one which is compatible with latest versions of OS.